# How to broadcast multiple channels in one event?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a custom event that implements `ShouldBroadcastNow` and broadcasts to a public channel.

As the `broadcastOn` function just returns one channel.

I've already tried to create a custom listener but couldn't implement `ShouldBroadcastNow`

```
 public function broadcastOn()
{
    // foreach($this->ticket->intersectRouteDetails);
    return new Channel('route-details.'.$this->ticket->routeDetails->id);
}
```

what I need is a way to loop with the commented collection to change the channel name.

Is there a way to broadcast multiple channels in this event?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share your implementation for more clarification.
Moreover you can refer this link once: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting

Comment: @Chang I edited my post

Comment: @BeshoyTamry have you tried passing channels as an array?

Comment: @KamalPaliwal No, How to do that?

Comment: @BeshoyTamry did you find the fix to this? I've tried `return [new PrivateChannel("chan1"), new PrivateChannel("chan2")];` and the queue just infinitely "processing" and doesn't run.

Comment: @ConnorSimpson yes, I just put the event trigger ``event(new eventName($varialbe))`` inside a foreach loop and passed the channel identifier

Comment: @BeshoyTamry Oh I see, that's one way around it I guess, I think Laravel should expand on broadcasting to allow this seamlessly.